# How to make this kind of layout. Please see details

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, floating-action-button

Here is an image:

[image]

What I want to know is that how to make this kind of layout?

Specially:

1- Invisible status bar.

2- Invisible Toolbar.

3- The floating action button over the image and the view below it.

Please let me know.

Sorry for bad formatting of the question. I'm still a beginner here.

Comment: you can create a scrolling activity from the "new activity" menu.

Answer (score 1):

The Activity is shown in the picture is ScrollingActivity.
Add design library in your dependencies. and create an Activity like the below. And add some extra things shown in picture. 
Enable backbutton by `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` . set a Background image on CollapsingToolbarLayout

**ScrollActivity.java**

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_scroll.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image"   <!-- Background Image -->
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling2" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

**content_scroll.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_scrolling2">

<!-- Add your Views -->


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```